# Where can I find statistics for the current RBF adoption?

Tags: replace-by-fee, statistics

What's the percentage of on-chain transactions having RBF (replace-by-fee) activated the last 30 days?

What query could I run against my node to find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://transactionfee.info/charts/transactions-signaling-explicit-rbf/, ~27% of transactions have signaled for RBF.

Bitcoin Core does not record this information by itself. You will need to compute the statistic yourself by inspecting each transaction. This can be achieved using the `getblock` RPC to get a block, then you would need to inspect each transaction and see if any input's sequence number is less than or equal to `0xfffffffd`.

Comment: 0xfffffffd or 0xfffffffe?

Comment: @bordalix `<= 0xfffffffd`. `0xfffffffe` was kept as a non-signaling value to allow opting in to `nLockTime` without opting to RBF signaling.